# How can I add the country name to a dataset based on city name and population?

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have a dataset containing information on a range of cities, but there is no column which says what country the city is located in. In order to perform the analysis, I need to add an extra column which has the name of the country.

```
population    city
500,000       Oslo
750,000       Bristol
500,000       Liverpool
1,000,000     Dublin
```

I expect the output to look like this:

```
population    city          country
500,000       Oslo          Norway
750,000       Bristol       England
500,000       Liverpool     England
1,000,000     Dublin        Ireland
```

How can I add a column of country names based on the city and population to a large dataset in R?

Comment: I don't really see how this is an R coding question without a file which maps cities to countries - do you have this?

Comment: I dont. The data is not that big that I cant do it manually. F.ex Bristol could appear 5/300 times in the dataset, so I would need a code that could print "England" in the new column on all rows that has "bristol" in the city column

Comment: Right... but all four cities you have given also exist in the US. Without the data to map them this is not an R coding question. I am going to vote to close this until you have that data but feel free to edit or ask another question once you do.

Comment: There is a country/city API as well that is a bit more extensive than the data in the `maps` package, but this doesn't solve the other issues people have brought up. `cities <- httr::GET("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries")`
`cities <- httr::content(cities)$data`

Comment: I am sorry, but too be more clear: I dont need an automatic fill in. I know the countries the cities are located in. I would need to create an empty column, then fill in all the rows with Bristol with England, and all the rows with Dublin with Ireland f.ex. If thats more understandable?

Comment: @M-- I am hesitant to start a reopen war, but I am not sure this is a reasonable duplicate target. In this question, the author has a city name *and* a population. In the duplicate, the author has a single column which may contain the country name but may not. I think they are different enough to not be a duplicate. Moreover, I think Tom's solution is the best answer to the duplicate target. If anything, the duplicate closure should be the other way.

Answer (score 2):

I am adapting Tom Hoel's answer, as suggested by Ian Campbell. If this is selected I am happy to mark it as community wiki.

```r
library(maps)
library(dplyr)
data("world.cities")

df <- readr::read_table("population    city
500,000       Oslo
750,000       Bristol
500,000       Liverpool
1,000,000     Dublin")


df   |>
  inner_join(
    select(world.cities, name, country.etc, pop), 
    by = c("city" = "name")
  )  |> group_by(city)  |> 
  filter(
    abs(pop - population) == min(abs(pop - population))
    )
        
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   city [4]
#   population city      country.etc     pop
#        <dbl> <chr>     <chr>         <int>
# 1     500000 Oslo      Norway       821445
# 2     750000 Bristol   UK           432967
# 3     500000 Liverpool UK           468584
# 4    1000000 Dublin    Ireland     1030431
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, the cities exists in other countries too as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)

data("world.cities")

df <- read_table("population    city
500,000       Oslo
750,000       Bristol
500,000       Liverpool
1,000,000     Dublin")

df %>% 
  merge(., world.cities %>%
          select(name, country.etc), 
        by.x = "city", 
        by.y = "name") 

# A tibble: 7 × 3
  city      population country.etc
  <chr>          <dbl> <chr>      
1 Bristol       750000 UK         
2 Bristol       750000 USA        
3 Dublin       1000000 USA        
4 Dublin       1000000 Ireland    
5 Liverpool     500000 UK         
6 Liverpool     500000 Canada     
7 Oslo          500000 Norway
```

Comment: I like this - using this dataset makes it an R question. But if you're going to do it this way then why not add to the end of the pipe `group_by(city)  |> filter(abs(pop - population) == min(abs(pop - population)))` ? Then you get one match per city, based on wherever has the closest population.

Answer (score -2):

I think your best bet would be to add a new column in your dataset called country and fill it out, this is part of the CRSIP-DM process data preparation so this is not uncommon. If that does not answer your question please let me know and i will do my best to help.

Comment: Do you have a code that could make this example possible? F.ex Bristol could appear 5/300 times in the dataset, so I would need a code that could print "England" in the new column on all rows that has "bristol" in the city column

Comment: If you do not want to do it manually then you can just add the column country and add a switch statement where if "bristol" comes up than country == England, and do the same for all the other cities. Its what i would do, but looking at the example above i am confused because you have liverpool > UK and liverpool > canada